# Perl dependency tree solver

Tags: perl, dependencies, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to come up with a creative way to determine dependencies so I can launch a regression of tests in the correct sequence.

For example:

```
a: d, e, f

b: c, d

c: f

d: e
```

Which means that test "a" depends on the completion of tests "d, e, and f" and so on.

I have the following code which will print the "leaf" nodes "e" and "f", however I'm stuck on how to go about traversing up and printing the parent nodes.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
my @input = ("a:d,e,f", "b:c,d", "c:f", "d:e");
my %Tests = ();
my %Built = ();

## Build Structure
foreach my $elem (@input) {
     my $depends = [];
     my $target;
     ($target,$depends) = parseData($elem);
     $Tests{$target} = $depends; ## Setting array ref to hashkey $target     
}


sub parseData {
  my $data = shift;
  my ($target, $deps) = split(/:/, $data);
  my @deps;
  @deps = split(/,/, $deps);
  return ($target,\@deps);
}

foreach my $key (keys %Tests) {
  doIT(\%Tests, \%Built, $key);
}

sub doIT {
 my ($testRef, $builtRef, $target) = @_;
 my $depends = $testRef->{$target};
 if(exists $builtRef->{$target}) {
   return;
 }
 if(!$depends) {
   ## No dependency, build it
   print "RunTest($target)\n";
   $builtRef->{$target}++;
   return;
 }

 foreach my $dep (@$depends) {
    doIT($testRef, $builtRef, $dep);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always the brute force method.  I'll let someone else come up with something clever:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = ("a:d,e,f", "b:c,d", "c:f", "d:e");

my %children;
my %parents;

for (@input) {
    my ($parent, @kids) = split /[:,]/;
    for (@kids) {
        $children{$parent}{$_}++;
        $children{$_} ||= {};
        push @{$parents{$_}}, $parent;
    }
}

my @order;
while (my $count = scalar keys %children) {
    while (my ($p, $k) = each %children) {
        if (! keys %$k) {
            push @order, $p;
            delete $children{$p};
            delete $children{$_}{$p} for @{$parents{$p}};
        }
    }

    die "circular dependency exists" if $count == scalar keys %children;
}

print "@order";
```

Comment: This is neat method!  I don't quite understand what the following line is doing:  $children{$_} ||= {}.  Can you elaborate on what this actually doing?  Thanks!

Comment: `%children` holds the parent to child relationships in a hash of hash structure.  `$children{$a_parent}{$a_child} = 1`.  Since some elements (like `e` and `f` don't have any children, I initialize that structure anytime I see a child.  To see the format of the data structure, just do `use Data::Dump; dd\%children;` after the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You would be best to use a graph module like Graph::Directed.  For example, the following gives an ordering that satisfies your dependencies:

```
use Graph::Directed;

my $graph = Graph::Directed->new();

my @edges = qw(d a e a f a c b d b f c e d);
while (my ($from, $to) = splice @edges, 0, 2) {
    $graph->add_edge($from, $to);
}
my @order = $graph->toposort();
print "@order\n";
```

It produces output

```
f e c d a b
```

Comment: When I implement this, I wind up with the output in the reverse order -- that is, tests always depend on later tests. So I think you probably need to reverse the result of `$graph->toposort()` before using...

Comment: Hmm.  I get exactly the output I have shown.  It is true that some of the Graph::Directed routines have changed their calling sequence in incompatible ways since the 0.3 version I originally used, but none of the methods in this example were affected.  I cannot explain why you would get the opposite order.  The latest Graph::Directed also has a $graph->topological_sort routine that produces "e d f c b a".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an object-oriented example using [MooX::Role::DependsOn](http://metacpan.org/pod/MooX%3a%3aRole%3a%3aDependsOn).

```
use feature 'say';

# Class (representing a 'job') that consumes MooX::Role::DependsOn:
package Task;
use Moo;
with 'MooX::Role::DependsOn';

sub execute {
  my ($self) = @_;
  say "execute called for job ".$self->dependency_tag;
}

package main;
# Create some objects that consume MooX::Role::DependsOn:
my $job = {};
for my $jobname (qw/ A B C D E F /) {
  $job->{$jobname} = Task->new(dependency_tag => $jobname)
}

# Add some dependencies:
# A depends on D, E, F
$job->{A}->depends_on( $job->{D}, $job->{E}, $job->{F} );
# B depends on C, D
$job->{B}->depends_on( $job->{C}, $job->{D} );
# C depends on F
$job->{C}->depends_on( $job->{F} );
# D depends on E
$job->{D}->depends_on( $job->{E} );

# Resolve dependencies for an object:
say "Object A:";
my @ordered = $job->{A}->dependency_schedule;
for my $obj (@ordered) {
  $obj->execute;
}
```